# How to manage y-axis values of high chart

Tags: highcharts

I am having data values which I am showing in high chart. But there neither negative value nor decimal value in my data , but than also my y-axis values have decimal value and start value of chart is -50 which need to be 500.
Kindly suggest how can i correct this issue , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `min` and `max` for yAxis. Then to prevent decimals set `allowDecimals` to false.

Refs:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max